# Why is psycopg2 INSERT taking so long to run in a loop and how do I speed it up?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert (source_lat, source_long, destination_lat, destination_long) rows from a Pandas dataframe into a PostgreSQL table (gmaps) using psycopg2 INSERT in a for loop. The table has an integrity constraint that prevents duplicate (source_lat, source_long, destination_lat, destination_long) rows from being inserted, so I am catching any duplicates with a try except block. My code is below.

I am iterating through every row in the dataframe (about 100000 rows) and calling cursor.execute(INSERT) on each row, seeing if that throws an integrity error, if it doesn't, I insert that row in the gmaps table.

However, this piece of code takes forever to run - how could I speed it up? I'm not sure where the overhead lies? Thank you!

Ele is a tuple that holds (source_lat, source_long, destination_lat, destination_long)

```
for ele in coordinates:
#Inserts new row to table
      try:
         cursor.execute('INSERT INTO gmaps (source_latitude, source_longitude, destination_latitude, destination_longitude) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (ele[0], ele[1], ele[2], ele[3])))
      except psycopg2.IntegrityError:
         conn.rollback()
      else:
         conn.commit()
```

Comment: It is not the code but the database refuse the action. You can try if it is fast when you   directly insert value into the database.

Comment: Executing 100000 separate INSERT statements is going to be slow.  No way around it.

Answer (score 3):

There a multiple options to speed up inserting bulk data.

1.) `commit()` after the loop is finished:

```
for ele in coordinates:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO gmaps (source_latitude, source_longitude, destination_latitude, destination_longitude) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (ele[0], ele[1], ele[2], ele[3])))
conn.commit()
```

2.) Use psycopg2's [fast execution helpers](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers), like `execute_batch() or execute_values()`.

3.) String concentraction using `mogrify()`:

```
dataText = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s,%s)', row) for ele in coordinates)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO gmaps VALUES ' + dataText)
cur.commit()
```

For a detailed comparison of `INSERT` execution speeds have a look at [this](http://aaronolszewski.com/psycopg2-execution-time/) benchmark.