# Which is Preferable option while performing data upsert using python psycopg2 to postgres?

Tags: python, cursor, psycopg2, query-performance, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to update and insert rows in a large postgres table comprising approx 30 millions of records using psycopg2 in python, I am doing so in batches of 100K records(~It takes 6 minutes for one batch) as I don't want to open the transaction for too long as to avoid creating row locking as the table rows are used by other transactions too while I am writing them. I am opening and closing the connection and the cursor every time in a loop .

so to update/insert via cursors in postgres which one (or none) of the below is preferable to avoid locks and also get better performance?

1> Opening the connection as well as closing the connection with every batch.

- open the connection for the batch.
- open the cursor for the batch.
- commit the transaction for the batch.
- close the cursor for the batch.
- close the connection for the batch.

2> Opening and closing the connection once but opening the cursor alone every time with every batch.

- open the connection once.
- open the cursor for the batch.
- commit the transaction for the batch.
- close the cursor for the batch.
- close the connection after the last batch.

Please advice if there's a better option as well. Currently I am using cursor.execute to execute insert/update queries but due to not so fast performance ,I have to choose batching. Since I don't have enough permissions to play with dropping the indexes while insert, I am using the route of batching.

**Queries used :-**

**Update:-**

```
UPDATE target_tbl tgt
        set descr = stage.descr,
        prod_name = stage.prod_name,
        item_name = stage.item_name,
        url       = stage.url,
        col1_name = stage.col1_name,
        col2_name = stage.col2_name,
        col3_name = stage.col3_name,
        col4_name = stage.col4_name,
        col5_name = stage.col5_name,
        col6_name = stage.col6_name,
        col7_name = stage.col7_name,
        col8_name = stage.col8_name,
        flag      = stage.flag
    from tbl1 stage
    where 
    tgt.col1 = stage.col1
    and tgt.col2 = stage.col2
    and coalesce(tgt.col3, 'col3'::text) = coalesce(stage.col3, 'col3'::text)
    and coalesce(tgt.col4, 'col4'::text) = coalesce(stage.col4, 'col4'::text);
```

**Insert:-**

```
 Insert into tgt
    select 
    stage.col1,
    stage.col2,
    stage.col3,
    stage.col4
    stage.prod_name,
    stage.item_name,
    stage.url,
    stage.col1_name,
    stage.col2_name,
    stage.col3_name,
    stage.col4_name,
    stage.col5_name,
    stage.col6_name,
    stage.col7_name,
    stage.col8_name,
    stage.flag
    from tbl1 stage
    where NOT EXISTS (
    select from tgt where
    tgt.col1 = stage.col1
    and tgt.col2 = stage.col2
    and coalesce(tgt.col3, 'col3'::text) = coalesce(stage.col3, 'col3'::text)
    and coalesce(tgt.col4, 'col4'::text) = coalesce(stage.col4, 'col4'::text)
    ) ;
```

Comment: Go with option 2, opening/closing the connection takes time and there is usually no benefit. Personally, I would try to insert faster first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330149/why-is-psycopg2-insert-taking-so-long-to-run-in-a-loop-and-how-do-i-speed-it-up/57337636#57337636

Comment: Thanks @Maurice Meyer for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Upsert function that requires no SQL coding on your python side only using the power of SQLAlchemy.

You can also decide on the batch size, I have used with batch size of 1000 but you can experiment with bigger.

Consider this function if you have a List of dictionaries and SQL Table that contain the same column names and types already. If you are using a DataFrame you can simply do a df.to_dict('records') and you will obtain the List of dictionaries that is ready for input.

**Make sure that you Dict keys and Table columns match**

```
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import Engine as sql_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from typing import List, Dict

engine = create_engine(...)


def upsert_database(list_input: List[Dict], engine: sql_engine, table: str, schema: str) -> None:
    if len(list_input) == 0:
        return None
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        base = automap_base()
        base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, schema=schema)
        target_table = Table(table, base.metadata,
                             autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema=schema)
        chunks = [list_input[i:i + 1000] for i in range(0, len(list_input), 1000)]
        for chunk in chunks:
            stmt = insert(target_table).values(chunk)
            update_dict = {c.name: c for c in stmt.excluded if not c.primary_key}
            conn.execute(stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
                constraint=f'{table}_pkey',
                set_=update_dict)
            )
```