# How increate efffciency insert data in PostGIS with Python?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, postgis

I need to insert 46mln points into PostGIS database in a decent time. Inserting 14mln points was executing around 40 minutes, it its awful and inefficient.

I created database with spatial GIST index and wrote this code:

```
import psycopg2
import time

start = time.time()

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', port='5432', dbname='test2', user='postgres', password='alfabet1')

filepath = "C:\\Users\\nmt1m.csv"
curs = conn.cursor()
with open(filepath, 'r') as text:
    for i in text:
        i = i.replace("\n", "")
        i = i.split(sep=" ")
        curs.execute(f"INSERT INTO nmt_1 (geom, Z) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINTZ({i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]})',0), {i[2]});")
conn.commit()
end = time.time()

print(end - start)

curs.close()
conn.close()
```

Im looking for the best way to inserting data, it not must be in python.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337636/7216865 or https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cześć! Welcome to SO.

There are a few things you can do to speed up your bulk insert:

1. If the target table is empty or is not being used in a production system, consider dropping the indexes right before inserting the data. After the insert is complete you can recreate them. This will avoid PostgreSQL to re-index your table after every insert, which in your case means 46 million times.
2. If the target table can be entirely built from your CSV file, consider creating an [`UNLOGGED TABLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59590141/2275388). Unlogged tables are much faster than "normal" tables, since they (as the name suggests) are not logged in the WAL file (write-ahead log). Unlogged tables might be lost in case of database crash or an unclean shutdown!
3. Use either the PostgreSQL [`COPY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59590141/2275388) command or [`copy_from`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) as @MauriceMeyer pointed out. If for some reason you must stick to inserts, make sure you're not committing after every insert ;-)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Jim for help, according to your instructions better way to insert data is:

```
import psycopg2
import time

start = time.time()
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', port='5432', dbname='test2',
user='postgres', password='alfabet1')
curs = conn.cursor()
filepath = "C:\\Users\\Jakub\\PycharmProjects\\test2\\testownik9_NMT\\nmt1m.csv"

curs.execute("CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE nmt_10 (id_1 FLOAT, id_2 FLOAT, id_3 FLOAT);")

with open(filepath, 'r') as text:
     curs.copy_from(text, 'nmt_10', sep=" ")

curs.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('nmt_10', 'geom', 2180, 'POINTZ', 3);")
curs.execute("CREATE INDEX nmt_10_index ON nmt_10 USING GIST (geom);")
curs.execute("UPDATE nmt_10 SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(id_1, id_2, id_3), 2180);")

conn.commit()
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

cheers